# How can i parse remote html page using pure java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing

I have a requirement to Parse remote html page ( ex: www.mywesite.com/home) how can i get this website html page source and how can i parse this page

that html is like this

```
 <html>
     <body>
        <div class="my-class1">
             <a href="home/link?id=1">hello</a>
        </div>

        <div class="my-class1">
             <a href="home/link?id=2">hey</a>
        </div>

        <div class="my-class1">
             <a href="home/link?id=3">bye</a>
        </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

i want output as

```
 hello
 hey
 bye
```

I'm not using any server side technology(like java, .net) i want to achieve this using java script only

is it possible to parse remote html page using Pure javaScript or any other jQuery plugin

thanks in advance

Comment: That is not possible due to Same Origin Policy

Comment: @Amberlamps so how can i achieve this any another way ???

Comment: you can only do it server-side.

Comment: @fredrik - (asuming I understand) I disagree.  am using this technique extensively for same-origin subpages via ajax

Comment: @ccyoung As far as I've understood it, if the current page is loaded from `www.somedomain.com` then you cannot ajax to `www.someotherdomain.com`, which is what he's trying to do. Of course you can always disable the policy.

Comment: @fredrik - you are correct.  I was not appreciating the cross-domain problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary browser javascript cannot access the contents of remote pages from any server except its own.

You can:

1. Have a cooperating script on your own server to fetch the remote content
2. With the cooperation of the remote server, you may be able to access content with an appropriate CORS ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing ) arrangement.
3. Again with the cooperation of the remote server, if it makes its content available by javascript you can access that by creating inline script elements. "JSONP" is an example of this approach.
4. If you write a browser plugin or addon - for browsers which permit such things to be written in javascript - then you are not bound by the browser security model in the same way.

Answer (score -2):

assuming `origin` fixed etc, here is the approach I use:

```
// get body part of html
txt = txt.substr( txt.indexOf('<body>')+6 );
txt = txt.substr( 0, txt.indexof('</body>')-1 );

// stick body into div
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = txt;

// extract textContent from each element (or something more interesting)
Array.prototype.slice( div.querySelectorAll('*') ).forEach( function(el) {
   if( el.textContent ) console.log( el.textContent );
});
```

Comment: how can i get body part of remote server html page lets say stackoverflow.com page from my server

Comment: @sunny you can't with javascript, same-origin policy as described previously. you'd need server-side code.