# How to extract meta tags for multiple product pages using page URL's?

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

There are about 200 product numbers and associated product URL's. I have to extract the meta tags wrt to title and keywords to each of these products using JavaScript code and output them to a file in my computer. How ?

example: product no: D2650, has the product URL: http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/D2650?lang=en&region=US

- This is similar to the rest of the 199 products. I need to extract the meta "keywords" and meta "title" for all these pages.

Help with JS code shall be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the set of pages you need to get metadata about, this existing API might do a good job extracting the info you need. 
https://opengraph.io/

It's a simple REST API:
`GET https://opengraph.io/api/1.0/site/<URL encoded site URL>`

It works well for pages that use the opengraph tags. And for other pages, it can sometimes fall back on grabbing other metadata tag info. You can test out what info it can find on a particular page with the test tool here:
https://opengraph.io/app/#!/debugtool

It's working well for me in a project, and saved me from extra time to hook up YQL or make other server-side changes. [NOTE: I have no relationship to this product or its creators. I found it through online research and used it in a project.]

Comment: this is the best answer across multiple similar questions on this topic, thanks @Rebecca

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pure javascript, you could do something like this:

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); //get all the meta tag elements

//iterate through them
for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
   if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == "keywords") { 
     console.log(metas[i].getAttribute("content")); 
   }
  else if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == "description") { 
     console.log(metas[i].getAttribute("content")); 
   } 
}
```

The above code could be simpler if you are using Jquery:

```
var keywords = $('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");
var description = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
```

I have given the code snippet as per the source of the [url](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/D2650?lang=en&region=US) you shared. You can modify the same to suit your needs. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

**EDIT**

I can understand you're a beginner but I am going to refrain from posting the entire code from beginning to the end simply because there are several ways of doing it and it's something you should and can learn on your own if you try. It is not that tough.

The starting point in your problem should be accessing the `html` of a remote source in javascript. We generally do this using a `post` or a `get` request but cross-origin network requests are generally disallowed in browsers. Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15812224/1083314) which elaborates on this issue.

Now, a simple workaround for this would be to look for `APIs` that allow you to scrape HTML from the online resources. [YQL(Yahoo Query Language)](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/#get-started) is one such tool that lets you 'query' html from remote sources. They have a very friendly [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) as well that generates a URL where you can directly make a `post` request and query the `html`. It is very well documented as well and should be very easy to get started with. Try the following yql query in the console :

```
 select * from html where url='http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/D2650?lang=en&region=US' and xpath='/html/head/meta'
```

Just look at the result and you would only have the `meta` tags returned in `XML` or `JSON` and a [custom URL](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fsigma%2FD2650%3Flang%3Den%26region%3DUS'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2Fhtml%2Fhead%2Fmeta'&diagnostics=true) generated for your yql query. So, it's just a matter of making a `get`/`post` request to that URL and then using the code I had posted earlier provided the data is returned as properly formatted `XML`. If it is returned as `JSON` you would have to simply parse the json which should also be quite simple.

All this probably sounds really complicated right now, but if you just get down to it, take it one step at a time, you'll be able to solve your problem yourself. Start by learning to use the YQL Console, making network requests in javascript and just put it all together. It **should** be a fun exercise.